# É possivel implementar um método de "Recycle Bin" em SAMBA?

Tags: linux, windows, samba

É possivel implementar um método de "Recycle Bin" em SAMBA?

Ou seja, quando um utilizador eliminar um ficheiro numa partilha SAMBA, é possivel enviá-lo para a "Lixeira", em vez de o eliminar definitivamente?

Se sim, que tipo de pacotes e configurações são necessárias implementar para que este método seja implementado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para se proceder à implementação de um "Caixote do lixo" em SAMBA, precisamos de pelo menos um pacote, uma dependência para a funcionalidade em questão:

## [vfs_recycle — Samba VFS recycle bin](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/vfs_recycle.8.html)

> O vfs_recycle intercepta os pedidos de eliminação para ficheiros e move os ficheiros afetados para um repositório temporário ao invés de os eliminar de forma permanente. Isto dá o mesmo efeito que a Lixeira em computadores Windows.

## Passo-a-passo

Para lidar com a questão de forma programática, podemos recorrer a um *script* em *bash* que vai passo a passo lidar com as verificações a serem feitas e no final adicionar ao ficheiro de configuração do SAMBA a entrada(s) necessária(s) para incluirmos nas diretorias a funcionalidade "Caixote do lixo":

1. Especificar o nome do pacote correto para a distribuição de Linux em uso, no exemplo usamos `samba-vfs`, mas por exemplo, em distribuições Ubuntu +14.04 o nome é `samba-vfs-modules`. Este pacote é uma dependência que permite implementar a referida funcionalidade "caixote do lixo";
2. Especificar o caminho para o ficheiro de configuração do SAMBA `smb.conf`, normalmente situado em `/etc/samba/smb.conf`;
3. Verificamos se o pacote está instalado, caso não, vamos executar um comando para o instalar. De notar que a forma como procedemos à verificação bem como o comando para instalar um pacote pode variar consoante a distribuição de Linux;
4. Preparamos as linhas de configuração a adicionar ao ficheiro `smb.conf`, onde deveremos especificar:

   ```sh
   [NomeUnico]
       path = /caminho/para/pasta/com/dados
       # Ativar caixote do lixo
       vfs object = recycle                        # objeto VFS, neste caso "recycle"
       recycle:repository = /minhaPasta/recycle/%U # caminho interno (*)
       recycle:keeptree = Yes                      # preservar estrutura de diretorias ?
       recycle:versions = Yes                      # preservar versões dos ficheiros ?
   ```

   <sup>(*)</sup> Caminho interno dentro do caixote do lixo para que cada utilizador não veja os seus ficheiros misturados com os dos outros utilizadores.
5. Por último, é preciso reiniciar o SAMBA. Aqui também podem existir divergências dado o comando correto poder variar consoante a distribuição de Linux.

## Exemplo

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Nome da dependência
PACKAGE_NAME="samba-vfs"

# Caminho para ficheiro de configuração do SAMBA
SAMBA_CFG_FILE="/etc/samba/smb.conf"

# Verificar se o pacote está instalado
PKG_OK=$(dpkg-query -W --showformat='${Status}\n' $PACKAGE_NAME|grep "install ok installed")
echo "A verificar se o pacote: $PACKAGE_NAME está instalado"

# Caso não tenha sido, instalar
if [ "" == "$PKG_OK" ]; then
  echo "Não está instalado, vamos instalar."
  sudo apt-get --force-yes --yes install $PACKAGE_NAME
fi

# Enviar texto para o fim desse ficheiro
echo "A adicionar ás configurações do SAMBA a entrada para: Partilhados"
sudo cat >> $SAMBA_CFG_FILE << EOL
[Partilhas]
    path = /zuul/Partilhas
    # Ativar caixote do lixo
    vfs object = recycle
    recycle:repository = /zuul/recycle/%U
    recycle:keeptree = Yes
    recycle:versions = Yes
EOL

# Reiniciar SAMBA
echo "Feito, a reiniciar SAMBA"
sudo service smbd restart
```

---

**Notas:**

Analisar atentamente o código antes de o executar, sob pena de danificar o sistema.

Este guia não dispensa a leitura da documentação oficial para o [vfs_recycle](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/vfs_recycle.8.html).

Para o *script* poder ser executado, o mesmo deverá estar com permissões de execução.